# узнать ID li элемента

Tags: javascript

Как при клике на элемент списка можно узнать его id, без использования атрибута  onclick в li. Только на чистом JS, без Jquery.

```
<ul id="drag" class="drag-element">
            <li id="red">Red</li>
            <li id="green">Green</li>
            <li id="blue">Blue</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onClick` вообще не рекомендуется использовать. Причин достаточно, см. гугл.
Чтобы не трогать вообще элементы `li`, можно делегировать обработчик на `ul` и с него определять `id`.
Приятная плюшка в том, что теперь можно динамически добавлять/убирать элементы `li` - код будет работать, тогда как навешивание кучи обработчиков на каждый элемент имеет две плохие стороны: на новые новые элементы действовать не будет и куча ненужных обработчиков, что плохо :)
Пример:

```js
document.querySelector('#drag').addEventListener('click', function(e){ // Вешаем обработчик клика на UL, не LI
  var id = e.target.id; // Получили ID, т.к. в e.target содержится элемент по которому кликнули
  document.querySelector('#test strong').innerHTML = id; // For example
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul id="drag" class="drag-element">
  <li id="red">Red</li>
  <li id="green">Green</li>
  <li id="blue">Blue</li>
</ul>

<!-- For example -->

<span id='test'>Вы выбрали <strong>ничего</strong></span>
```

Comment: Поправка: все-таки хранить цвет в id - не лучшая идея. Какой-нибудь `data-color` подойдет больше.

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Comment: igumnov, ваш вариант не будет работать, событие клик отрабатывается в цикле, еще до клика этот код будет отработан и не даст никакого результата. А если запускать данный код по клику, тогда нужен еще один клик во время отработки самого цикла, чтобы получить результат. С учетом, что это всё будет происходить в доли секунды после первого клика, никакого результата от этого кода не будет. Я бы использовал свойство event.target при клике на список.
вот как то так все получается: document.getElementById("drag").addEventListener("click", function() { var event = window.event.target, alert(event.id)

Comment: @Brood, а ты пробовал запускать код из ответа igumnov? Обрати внимание, что в цикле **не вызывается** обработчик. Он только **добавляется** к элементу.